# Builderx to expo

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

[image]Is it possible to open a project made in builderx? I found that tool and it is good, but when trying to emulate it with expo it gives me many mistakes, is there anyone who uses this tool? If so, can you tell me how I can emulate the project?

Comment: It should work as it is. Can you share the screenshot or DM me the project link so that I can have a look?

Comment: the project is in this link , i thought i should install some libraries https://builderx.io/app/o0h5f8llscg4gcs0g80go8ks4cgssw

Comment: Let me check and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I was solving some problems , then i saw a tutorial on youtube and now it show me this error , i try to run it on my device

Answer (score 4):

You can either download the whole project and then run `yarn` or `npm install`. Or you can download the component and then use it in your existing react native project.

If you are downloading a component in which some third party components are used, you will have to add those libraries manually in your existing project by `yarn add [library-name]` or `npm install [library-name] --save`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this

1. Save your project in `BuilderX`. It will give you the `Expo` project.
2. Go to the root of the project in terminal. run the following commands.
3. `"npm install"` or `"yarn"`
4. `"npm start"` or `"yarn start"`, once this command is run successfully, you'll get a QR code at the end of the output
5. Scan the QR code in Expo App of your mobile and It will run the project in Expo.

Comment: When I download my expo project, I download a zip where a folder called src, index.js and readme.md comes. After giving "yarn" in my root folder a folder called node_modules and yarn.lock is created, now I give yarn start and it says error Couldn't find a package.json file in the address of my folder

Comment: Could you try `npm install` ?

Comment: I read the documentation in react native and I could already launch the QR code, but once I see it on my android it throws me the error shown in the image above, I honestly don't know if third-party libraries should be installed or I don't understand

Comment: @JorgeCorante If you only see index.js and README file in your extracted folder, that means you have used "Download Component" which cannot be run on its own.

To get the full expo project, you need to open dropdown besides "Download Component" button and click on "Download Project"

Comment: thanks , that was my mistake lol i was downloading the components , no the project